# Capturing logging entries on code coverage

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven Surefire plugin to run my project's unit tests and Jacoco for code coverage. I have a strict coverage criteria in my project but my problem is that logging level specific lines are not captured by the Jacoco and messing up with my covering stats.
For example:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Log entry");
    }
```

Will fail to identify the log entry code line. Any way to work around it?

Comment: Why aren't you just running your tests in DEBUG logging level?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work when running the Maven goals. Not sure what to do

Comment: How did you try to move it to DEBUG? Can you share you pom.xml?